# VBA: Exporting WORD table to excel

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use this code in order to import to excel some data and to calculate the total of a row however I have  a ''Object required'' error when running pointing the For cycle. Any idea?

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
    Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
    Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
    Dim A As Integer
    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

    With wdDoc
        TableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
        If TableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
        ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
            TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
            "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
        End If
        
        
        
        If TableNo = 1 Or TableNo = 2 Then
        
            With .Tables(TableNo).Range.Copy
            
            Range("A1").Activate
            Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
        
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
            
              A = "=SUM(C6:L6)"
              
              InputBox ("Total" & A)
        End With
    End If
    End With
```

Comment: `.copy` is a method of a range object, don't put that in the with statement, it isn't an object itself and thus has no `.rows` property.

Comment: what could I use instead? thank you

Comment: With .Tables(TableNo).Range

Comment: iT doesn't work withou .copy

Comment: Just place your cursor in front of `.Range.Copy` and hit return. You will then have `With .Tables(TableNo)` on one line and `.Range.Copy` on the next. Your code will then work.

Comment: «I use this code in order to import to excel some data and to calculate the total of a row» Why? Word can do that without VBA!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code as a starting point sample. It is using early binding, but if that's not what you want it is easily changed. I also set it up with the Word document already open, but again, it can be easily changed to whatever way you want to access the Word document from Excel.

```
Sub GetWordTable()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application, doc As Word.Document
    Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set doc = wApp.ActiveDocument
    doc.Tables(1).Range.Copy
    
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
End Sub
```